# How can I put string in other string by position

Tags: lua, love2d

My string is `'Hllo'`.
I want to put inside it `'e'` after the `'H'` by its position, this case, position number 2.

Comment: ... and you don't want to rewrite l?

Comment: I do, I just need to place the 'e' in pos 2 and the rest of the string will be pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply cut contents until position you want to place your character on, then add the character and finally concat the characters on and after position.

```
src = "Hllo"
result = string.sub(src, 1, string.find(src, "H")) .. "e" .. string.sub(src, string.find(src, "H")+1)
```

The first part of code gets position of 'H' andf cuts the start (in this case 'H' only).
Second part adds character you want to insert. Third part adds every character after 'H' in source string to result.

Comment: Or more concisely, `src:sub(1, src:find("H")) .. "e" .. src:sub(src:find("H") + 1)`

Answer (score 6):

```
local str = 'Hllo'
str = str:gsub('()',{[2]='e'})
```

Comment: Very clever! I'd forgotten about position captures

Comment: I like! However the original question was to replace "by the position of `H`", which this variant does not do.

Answer (score -4):

you can try this out

`$arr = str_split('hllo',1);

$result=$arr[0].'e'.$arr[1].$arr[2].$arr[3]`